# Turn non-interleaved audio data into interleaved

Tags: iphone, ios, buffer, core-audio

I'm working with  modified version of Apple's MixerHost Class which separates audio into two streams in its callbacks (this is to allow for the resulting audio to be either mono or stereo). The result, clearly, is a non-interleaved stream. I'm new to Core Audio, I need an interleaved stream, and I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction to modify the buffers in a callback to store interleaved stereo data.

Thank you.

Here is one of the callbacks:

```
static OSStatus inputRenderCallback (

                                     void                        *inRefCon,      // A pointer to a struct containing the complete audio data 
                                     //    to play, as well as state information such as the  
                                     //    first sample to play on this invocation of the callback.
                                     AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags, // Unused here. When generating audio, use ioActionFlags to indicate silence 
                                     //    between sounds; for silence, also memset the ioData buffers to 0.
                                     const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,   // Unused here.
                                     UInt32                      inBusNumber,    // The mixer unit input bus that is requesting some new
                                     //        frames of audio data to play.
                                     UInt32                      inNumberFrames, // The number of frames of audio to provide to the buffer(s)
                                     //        pointed to by the ioData parameter.
                                     AudioBufferList             *ioData         // On output, the audio data to play. The callback's primary 
                                     //        responsibility is to fill the buffer(s) in the 
                                     //        AudioBufferList.
                                     ) {

    soundStructPtr    soundStructPointerArray   = (soundStructPtr) inRefCon;
    UInt32            frameTotalForSound        = soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].frameCount;
    BOOL              isStereo                  = soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].isStereo;

    // Declare variables to point to the audio buffers. Their data type must match the buffer data type.
    AudioUnitSampleType *dataInLeft;
    AudioUnitSampleType *dataInRight;

    dataInLeft                 = soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].audioDataLeft;
    if (isStereo) dataInRight  = soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].audioDataRight;

    // Establish pointers to the memory into which the audio from the buffers should go. This reflects
    //    the fact that each Multichannel Mixer unit input bus has two channels, as specified by this app's
    //    graphStreamFormat variable.
    AudioUnitSampleType *outSamplesChannelLeft;
    AudioUnitSampleType *outSamplesChannelRight;

    outSamplesChannelLeft                 = (AudioUnitSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    if (isStereo) outSamplesChannelRight  = (AudioUnitSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;

    // Get the sample number, as an index into the sound stored in memory,
    //    to start reading data from.
    UInt32 sampleNumber = soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].sampleNumber;

    // Fill the buffer or buffers pointed at by *ioData with the requested number of samples 
    //    of audio from the sound stored in memory.
    for (UInt32 frameNumber = 0; frameNumber < inNumberFrames; ++frameNumber) {

        if (sampleNumber == frameTotalForSound) {

            NSString *AudioFileDidFinishPlaying = @"AudioFileDidFinishPlaying";
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: AudioFileDidFinishPlaying object: nil];
            /*NSString *CloseExtAudioFile = @"CloseExtAudioFile";
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: CloseExtAudioFile object: nil];*/

        }

        outSamplesChannelLeft[frameNumber]                 = dataInLeft[sampleNumber];
        if (isStereo) outSamplesChannelRight[frameNumber]  = dataInRight[sampleNumber];

        sampleNumber++;

        // After reaching the end of the sound stored in memory--that is, after
        //    (frameTotalForSound / inNumberFrames) invocations of this callback--loop back to the 
        //    start of the sound so playback resumes from there.



        //NSLog (@"Audio file finished; stopping audio playback.");

    }

    // Update the stored sample number so, the next time this callback is invoked, playback resumes 
    //    at the correct spot.
    soundStructPointerArray[inBusNumber].sampleNumber = sampleNumber;

    return noErr;
}
```

Comment: From reading your question and code, I'm not really clear why this is necessary. It seems that you need to re-interlace the data at some point, but probably only before writing it to disk (based on your other question). BTW if you want to take this discussion offline, feel free to email me at nik (dot) reiman (at) gmail. I'd be happy to help you out.

Comment: The most general way to interleave or deinterleave in Core Audio is using an AudioConverter.  It's also possible to do it manually, of course, but generally AudioConverter is extremely optimized.  Do you want to interleave the samples in your callback for some reason?

Comment: I eventually realized that I didn't need to do this @sbooth. But thanks for the tip about using AudioConverter.

Comment: Hi, long shot, but I'm at a similar stage to you at the moment. How did you come to realize that you didn't need to do this? I have generated, non-interleaved data and I need to write it through ExtAudioFileWriteAsync, which is demanding interleaved.